# Unable to solve for roots using NSolve command

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the roots of the transcendental equation using `NSolve` function. I have a equation `P` which is a function of `K1,K2,K3` and `b`. I am inputting values for `K1,K2,K3` and solve for `b`.I am also trying to write a `Module` wherein I am in putting `K1,K2,K3` from a matrix `comb`. I am trying to automate the code.

```
P = b (b^3 Cos[b]^4 + b^2 K1 Cos[b]^3 Sin[b] + 
     b^2 K2 Cos[b]^3 Sin[b] - b^4 K2 Cos[b]^3 Sin[b] + 
     b^2 K3 Cos[b]^3 Sin[b] - b^4 K3 Cos[b]^3 Sin[b] + 
     b^6 K3 Cos[b]^3 Sin[b] + 3 b^5 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 - 
     2 b^7 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 + b^9 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 + 
     b K1 K2 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 + b K1 K3 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 - 
     b^3 K1 K3 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 + b K2 K3 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 - 
     b^3 K2 K3 Cos[b]^2 Sin[b]^2 + 2 b^4 K1 Cos[b] Sin[b]^3 - 
     b^6 K1 Cos[b] Sin[b]^3 + b^4 K2 Cos[b] Sin[b]^3 - 
     b^6 K2 Cos[b] Sin[b]^3 + b^4 K3 Cos[b] Sin[b]^3 + 
     K1 K2 K3 Cos[b] Sin[b]^3 + b^7 Sin[b]^4 + b^3 K1 K2 Sin[b]^4);
comb = Tuples[{0, 1*^8}, 3];
stiff = {K1, K2, K3}
P = P /. Table[stiff[[j]] -> comb[[1, j]], {j, 1, 3}];
Plot[P, {b, 0, 10}]
s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < b < 5]
```

Comment: As you can see from the plot, there are no roots for 0<b<5. There is a root at b==0.

Comment: Easier to see if you zoom in on the plot: `Manipulate[Plot[P, {b, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> pltRng, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 15], {{pltRng, 10^6, PlotRange}, 10^Range[-2, 6]}]`